# Populating a 3D list in python with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a [this](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/2/input) string, and I want to populate a structure with it. The structure is a list, called "mega". Each element in "mega" is a list containing 2 elements. Each of these, in turn, is a list of 4 elements. So overall we have a structure of the dimensions n*2*4.

I want to "break" the string in equal length (of 4 items each) "chunks". Each element of "mega" will contain in the first list the original indexes (referring to the input string index) of the "chunk"'s values, and the second list will contain the values of one "chunk".

So again: we take the input string, cut it to smaller strings, each one of the sub-strings is composed of 4 chars. For convenience we'll convert these chars to be integers. So each element in "mega" is a list of 2 items (each item is composed of 4 integers):

1st item - list of 4 integers that denotes the location of the values (see '2nd item') in the original input string. They will be consecutive.

2nd item - list of 4 integers, their value is taken from the original input string.

Actually what we're doing here is putting each of the values from the input string in one row of a n*2 "table", the other row will contain the index number for each value. Then we cut this table to chunks of 4, and populate a list with those chunks.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
import pyperclip
import math
import termtables as tt 

# Creating main_input from the txt file
# main_input is a list of strings
string = open("input01.txt").read()
main_input = string.split(",")

# Converting main_input values to integers
for i in range(len(main_input)):
    main_input[i] = int(main_input[i])

# print(main_input)

# Calculating number of the quadruplets
quad_num = int(math.ceil(len(main_input) / 4))
print('quad_num: ' + str(quad_num) + '\n')

# Initializing mega - a list of the quadruplets
mega = [None] * quad_num

# print(mega)

# Initializing each quadruplet as a list of 2 items
for i in range(len(mega)):
    mega[i] = [None] * 2

print('mega after duplication:\n')
print(mega)
print('\n')

# Each quadruplet is composed of 2 lists, each one contains 4 elements
for i in range(len(mega)):
    mega[i][0] = [None] * 4
    mega[i][1] = [None] * 4

print('mega after each quadruplication:\n')
print(mega)
print('\n')

# Index for iterating over mega
mega_index = 0

print('This is the main input: \n')
print(main_input)
print('\n')

# Populating "mega" 
for global_index in range(len(main_input) - 1):
    if (global_index % 4) == 0:
        for local_index in range(4):
            mega[mega_index][0][local_index] = int(global_index + local_index)
            mega[mega_index][1][local_index] = int(main_input[global_index + local_index])
        mega_index = mega_index + 1

print('This is mega afer populating:\n')
print(mega)
```

I have 2 problems with my code:

1. I had to change

`for global_index in range(len(main_input)):`

to

`for global_index in range(len(main_input) - 1):`

in order to not get an "out of index" error, and I'm not sure I understand why.

2. The output I'm getting is fine at the beginning, but when I look at the end of it and compare it to the original input string, it seems "out of sync".

It's probably something pretty basic that has to do with the counting of the `for` loops, but since I'm a beginner I'm having a difficulty un understanding what exactly is the problem. I would appreciate any help and guidance, thanks a lot if you read so far!

By the way, this thing is a part of my attempt to solve a problem from this year's [advent of code](https://adventofcode.com/) challenge, so please no spoilers (I know that what I'm trying to do is not necessary to solve the AOC problem, I'm doing it to improve my programming skills as an exercise I "invented" for myself while I was trying to solve the AOC challenge).

Comment: python starts with 0 as index and counts to n-1

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was basically due to the attempt to populate `mega` with values from `main_input` when the index for those source values (in `main_input`) was out of range. I solved it by prolongating the `main_input` length to the closest number divisible by 4 with 'Blank' values. Then I added a condition, when extracting from `main_input` during the population `for` loop, that checks to see if the next value in `main_input` is not 'Blank'.

```
import pyperclip
import math
import termtables as tt 

# Creating main_input from the txt file
# main_input is a list of strings
string = open("input01.txt").read()
main_input = string.split(",")

# Converting main_input values to integers
for i in range(len(main_input)):
    main_input[i] = int(main_input[i])

print(main_input)

if (len(main_input) % 4 != 0):
    if (len(main_input) % 4 == 1):
        main_input.append('Blank')
        main_input.append('Blank')
        main_input.append('Blank')
    if (len(main_input) % 4 == 2):
        main_input.append('Blank')
        main_input.append('Blank')
    if (len(main_input) % 4 == 3):
        main_input.append('Blank')

# Calculating number of the quadruplets
print('Length of main_input: ' + str(len(main_input)))
quad_num = int(math.ceil(len(main_input) / 4))
print('quad_num: ' + str(quad_num) + '\n')

# Initializing mega - a list of the quadruplets
mega = [None] * (quad_num)

# print(mega)

# Initializing each quadruplet as a list of 2 items
for i in range(len(mega)):
    mega[i] = [None] * 2

print('mega after duplication:\n')
print(mega)
print('\n')

# Each quadruplet is composed of 2 lists, each one contains 4 elements
for i in range(len(mega)):
    mega[i][0] = [None] * 4
    mega[i][1] = [None] * 4

print('mega after quadruplication:\n')
print(mega)
print('\n')

# Index for iterating over mega
mega_index = 0

print('This is the main input: \n')
print(main_input)
print('\n')

# Populating "mega" 
for global_index in range(len(main_input)):
    if (global_index % 4) == 0:
        for local_index in range(4):
            mega[mega_index][0][local_index] = int(global_index + local_index)
            if main_input[global_index + local_index] != 'Blank':
                mega[mega_index][1][local_index] = int(main_input[global_index + local_index])
        mega_index = mega_index + 1

print('This is mega afer populating:\n')
print(mega)
```